# UE5/C++ Progress Bar: Change a background image during runtime

Tags: c++, user-interface, widget, unreal-engine5

I'm quite new to UE, so I'm seeking for some help! Currently I'm working on HUD and faced some issues with Progress Bars. The goal is pretty simple, I need to change a background image of Progress Bar during runtime. According to my logging everything is working but it doesn't show any changes on Screen. I appreciate any help!

My code:

.h

```
    UPROPERTY(EditAnywhere, meta=(BindWidget))
    class UProgressBar* IconSlot1;
    UPROPERTY(EditAnywhere, meta=(BindWidget))
    class UProgressBar* IconSlot2;
    UPROPERTY(EditAnywhere, meta=(BindWidget))
    class UProgressBar* IconSlot3;
    UPROPERTY(EditAnywhere)
    TArray<class UIconSlot*> IconArr;
    UPROPERTY(VisibleAnywhere)
    TArray<class UProgressBar*> SlotArr;
```

.cpp

```
void UPlayerUI::SetSlotIcon(const TEnumAsByte<EDamageClass>& DamageClass)
{
    const auto EmptySlot = GetFreeSlot();
    const auto Icon = GetImage(DamageClass);

    if (IsValid(EmptySlot) && IsValid(Icon))
    {
        FProgressBarStyle Style = EmptySlot -> GetWidgetStyle();
        
            if (Style.BackgroundImage.GetResourceObject() == nullptr)
            {
                FSlateImageBrush Brush = FSlateImageBrush(Icon, FVector2d(100, 100));
                Style.SetBackgroundImage(Brush);
                UE_LOG(LogTemp, Warning, TEXT("Image slot is set"));
            }
            else
            {
                UE_LOG(LogTemp, Warning, TEXT("Image slot isn't empty"));
                return;
            }

            Slots.Add(EmptySlot, DamageClass);
    }
}
```

```
UProgressBar* UPlayerUI::GetFreeSlot()
{
    for (const auto IconSlot : SlotArr)
    {
        if (!Slots.Contains(IconSlot))
        {
            UE_LOG(LogTemp, Warning, TEXT("Slot found"));
            return IconSlot;
        }
    }
    
    return nullptr;
}
```

```
UTexture2D* UPlayerUI::GetImage(const TEnumAsByte<EDamageClass>& DamageClass)
{
    for (const auto IconImage : IconArr)
    {
        if (IconImage -> DamageClass == DamageClass && !Icons.Contains(IconImage))
        {
            UE_LOG(LogTemp, Warning, TEXT("Image found"));
            Icons.Add(IconImage, DamageClass);
            return IconImage -> Image;
        }
    }
    
    return nullptr;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resolved it by adding these lines:

```
Style = Style.SetBackgroundImage(Brush);
EmptySlot -> SetWidgetStyle(Style);
```